# Android IabHelper.queryInventoryAsync method returns incorrect product information

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I'm implementing in-App purchase in an Android App. I set up the App in the Google Play Developer Console and setup several products.

I added IabHelper and the associated billing files to my codebase per the Android docs. I'm able to successfully `setup`:

```
        String base64EncodedPublicKey = Configurations.getInstance().getGooglePlayLicenseKey();
        googlePlayHelper = new IabHelper(AtavistApplication.getContext(), base64EncodedPublicKey);
        googlePlayHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    Utilities.log("Unable to setup billing: " + result);
                    isBillingSetup = false;
                } else {
                    Utilities.log("Billing setup successfully");
                    isBillingSetup = true;
                }
            }
        });
```

But when I query Google Play for product information like so:

```
   IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mQueryFinishedListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory)
        {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                Utilities.log("getProducts failed");
                callback.failure(null);
            } else {
                Utilities.log("getProducts succeeded");
                callback.success(inventory);
            }
        }
    };

    googlePlayHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, identifiers, mQueryFinishedListener);
```

Where `identifiers` is a list of String product identifiers:

```
    ArrayList<String> productIDs = new ArrayList<String>();
    productIDs.add("com.first.product");
    productIDs.add("com.second.product");
    productIDs.add("com.third.product");
```

I get a successful response that contains only one product that isn't a product that's setup in my Google Play account. Its productID is the productID of a product that we have offered before but it was deleted from the Google Play list of active products a while ago.

**Questions:**

1. Why is `queryInventoryAsync` not returning the proper list?
2. Why on earth would it return a product that's not currently set up in Google Play?
3. Am I missing some basic configuration step that's causing this confusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there was some dissonance between the apk that I had uploaded to the Google Play Developer Console (before setting up the products) and the codebase/apk that I was building and testing with.

Specifically, the bundle identifier (package name) was different, and they were signed with different keystores.

No idea why this would return a seemingly valid product rather than an explicit error, but bringing the two apks in line resolved the issue.